# Xcode 5 Warning: Attribute Unavailable

Tags: ios, xcode5

I've updated my Xcode version to 5.0.

After this I got bunch of warnings which were not in my previous Xcode version.

The Warnings are these:

```
Attribute Unavailable
Attributed Text on iOS versions prior to 6.0

Attribute Unavailable
Minumum Font Scale on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

Anyone who have removed this warning?

Comment: Are you using the Minimum font scale attribute on labels in your XIBs and the base SDK for your app is < iOS6? Then I would change that to iOS 6, except if you still want to support old iOS versions. Minimum font scale is only available starting iOS 6 ...

Comment: @TheEye, thanks for your answer! :) I'll remove the property so I can still support iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest the problem is exactly what the error says. Your project is set to deploy on targets below iOS 6 and you have a XIB or Storyboard that uses Attributed Text, a feature that is not supported before iOS 6.

The fix is either:

- Change your minimum supported version to iOS 6
- Don't use Attributed text

Comment: thanks for answering. But I'm wondering why these warnings doesn't appear before. Anyway, I'll just modify to not use Attributed text. Thanks! :)

Comment: Newer versions of Xcode have newer and better compilers that spot more problems for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reason of the problem. However, using for example tintColor prior to iOS 6 doesn't crash the app on older versions. I don't want to change my minimum setting. I want to use attributed text on newer versions and ignore that setting on prior versions. Is there a way to suppress this error? I just don't want to see it everytime I build.

Comment: @MuratÖgat Make sure that your Storyboard doesn't reference anything that is not in your minimum supported version (in the case above that would be attributed strings). Then, in your code check the version at run time and use the feature where appropriate. For example, for a 'UILabel` you'd assign your text to `attributedText` rather than `text`.